# HTML Link with external CSS no working

Tags: html, css, web

When I try to link the following code to my CSS file, it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body"
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

style.css contents:

```
.body {
background-color: blue;
}
```

In the HTML file, the following that I put in bold is underlined with a red line in notepad++:
<-link href="style.**css**" type="text/**css**" rel="**stylesheet**"/>
*note the '-' in **link href=** was for demonstrational purposes.

Doesn't seem to work. The background color stays white. Any help?

Comment: If there's no content **inside** the `<div class="body"></div>` then it won't have any size to even have a background colour.

Comment: Yup you need to give the div a width and height, furthermore if you want the whole page blue, you shouldnt be setting a div inside, just use the selector `body` without the period

Comment: If you want to make the background of your entire page a specific colour use the body tag instead: `body { background: blue; }`

Answer (score 1):

Put some content in the div.

and close the div like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <style>
        body {
          background-color: blue;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body"> <!-- please check I closed this tag -->
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <style>
          body {
            background: blue;
          }
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You did not close your  tag as well as body. BTW You can set body to have background-color instead of a section inside it as it doesn't have any width and height set.

```
<div class="body">
</div>
</body> <!-- Close body -->
```

Answer (score -1):

please check your path of the CSS file.

or else you can put internal CSS using style tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <style>
        body {
          background-color: blue;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't do anything, because the `div` has no content and therefore is of zero width and zero height.

Answer (score -1):

1 - make sure your style.css is not in another directory on the server

2 - you do not need to call a class for the body it already takes priority.

Use this and remove the class=body div :)

```
body {
background-color: #000000;}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could just put it as

```
body {
background-color: blue;
}
```

in the stylesheet, and also there won't be a need for

```
<div class="body">
</div>
```

which you didn't close the tag properly anyways!

also you can use id to style the div `div id = body`

in css it would be

```
#body{
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: `#body` would style an element with the id of `body`, which does not exist.

Comment: yeah i misread the question's div class as div id! my bad. thank you :-)